# JUnit 4 API Get Handle to a @Test Method

Tags: junit, junit4, junit-runner

Using JUnit 4 API, is there a way to get a *handle* to a method in a test class that are annotated with `@Test`?

Here's what I am currently doing:

```
JUnitCore core = new JUnitCore();
Request request = Request.aClass(MyTest.class);
Result result = core.run(request);
if(result.wasSuccessful())
    System.out.println("SUCCESS"); // or do something else
```

This code will run all tests in `MyTest`. However, what I want is to just specify the test class name at the beginning (`MyTest.class`) and do following in a loop:

- Get next `@Test` annotated test in the class.
- Print details
- Run the test (possibly using `Request.method(MyTest.class, "myTestMethod")`

I can perhaps use reflection to get the method names and check if they are annotated with Test, but wanted to see if the JUnit API already provides this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`TestClass`](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runners/model/TestClass.html):

```
public void runTests(Class<?> clazz) {
  TestClass testClass = new TestClass(MyTest.class);
  List<FrameworkMethod> tests = testClass.getAnnotatedMethods(
      Test.class);
  for (FrameworkMethod m : tests) {
    String methodName = m.getName();
    Request request = Request.method(clazz, methodName);
    JUnitCore core = new JUnitCore();
    Result result = core.run(request);
    if (result.wasSuccessful())
      System.out.println(m + ": SUCCESS");
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this is an inefficient way to run tests, especially if you have class rules or you use `@BeforeClass` or `@AfterClass`

Comment: Perfect! just what I was looking for. I am actually exploring load testing my junits with Grinder and unfortunately, running each test separately is the only way I can get their details and report on them individually. Thanks.

Comment: @HP Your welcome. You can also use `Request.filter)()`